# New TypeScript syntax recognition in Intellij IDEA 2016.3

Tags: typescript

I use Intellij Idea 2016.3 and TypeScript 2.1.5 and now I'm experiencing the problem [image: 1]
In this code I used new keyword "keyof" that appeared in TS 2.1. This code correctly works at official typescript playground and successfully compiled by "tsc" on my computer but looks like IDEA just doesn't recognize this syntax. I tried to turn off/on TS service, change TS version to 2.2.1 - doesn't help. Just have no idea how to fix that. Please help.

Comment: I had the same issue with Webstorm, the only thing that solved it was to update to the latest Webstorm version.

Comment: @NitzanTomer Thanx, that helped!

Answer (score 0):

I just updated IDEA to 2016.3.5 and that solved the problem